# Spark: Dataframe pipe delimited doesn't return correct values

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, split

I have data frame as below:

```
scala> products_df.show(5)
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|1009|45|Diamond F...|
|1010|46|DBX Vecto...|
|1011|46|Old Town ...|
|1012|46|Pelican T...|
|1013|46|Perceptio...|
+--------------------+
```

I need to divide each column wise-

I use below query which works in all the other delimiter but here it doen't ==>

```
products_df.selectExpr(("cast((split(value,'|'))[0] as int) as product_id"),("cast((split(value,'|'))[1] as int) as product_category_id"),("cast((split(value,'|'))[2] as string) as product_name"),("cast((split(value,'|'))[3] as string) as description"), ("cast((split(value,'|'))[4] as float) as product_price") ,("cast((split(value,'|'))[5] as string) as product_image")).show
```

It returns -

```
product_id|product_category_id|product_name|description|product_price|product_image|
+----------+-------------------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|         1|                  0|           0|          9|         null|            4|
|         1|                  0|           1|          0|         null|            4|
|         1|                  0|           1|          1|         null|            4|
|         1|                  0|           1|          2|         null|            4|
|         1|                  0|           1|          3|         null|            4|
|         1|                  0|           1|          4|         null|            4|
|         1|                  0|           1|          5|         null|            4|
```

It works fine when the file is delimited by comma(,) or (:)
only with pipe(|) and returns above values whereas it should be

```
product_id|product_category_id|        product_name|description|product_price|       product_image|
+----------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------+
|      1009|                 45|Quest Q64 10 FT. ...|           |        59.98|http://images.acm...|
|      1010|                 46|Under Armour Men'...|           |       129.99|http://images.acm...|
|      1011|                 47|Under Armour Men'...|           |        89.99|http://images.acm...|
```

Comment: How are you loading your file ? If it is csv then  use Use  option("delimiter", "|") example: spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv(file) or sep instead of delimiter.

Comment: What about split by `split(value, "\\|")`?

Comment: I am sqooping it in required pipe delimited format.i tried using escape but of no use.

Comment: @alam this  problem seems to me with selectExpr  split for pipe separator only bcoz if you will do withColumn   df2.withColumn("t",split($"value","\\|")(0)).show it is giving me expected result. so you can try using withcolumn .

Comment: @ Mahesh - Thanks it works ---It looks as below now val products_df=spark.read.textFile("/user/products").withColumn("product_id",split($"value","\\|")(0).cast("int")).withColumn("product_cat_id",split($"value","\\|")(1).cast("int")).withColumn("product_name",split($"value","\\|")(2).cast("string")).withColumn("product_description",split($"value","\\|")(3).cast("string")).withColumn("product_price",split($"value","\\|")(4).cast("float")).withColumn("product_image",split($"value","\\|")(5).cast("string")).select("product_id","product_cat_id","product_name","product_de......)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, Guys for the suggestions- 
-> It seems selectExpr doesn't work  when file is delimited by pipe(|).
so the alternate way is to use withColumn.

val products_df=spark.read.textFile("/user/code/products").withColumn("product_id",split($"value","\|")(0).cast("int")).withColumn("product_cat_id",split($"value","\|")(1).cast("int")).withColumn("product_name",split($"value","\|")(2).cast("string")).withColumn("product_description",split($"value","\|")(3).cast("string")).withColumn("product_price",split($"value","\|")(4).cast("float")).withColumn("product_image",split($"value","\|")(5).cast("string")).select("product_id","product_cat_id","product_name","product_description","product_price","product_image")

Answer (score 0):

> Spark 2.4.3 Just adding a neat and clean code

```
scala> var df =Seq(("1009|45|Diamond F"),("1010|46|DBX Vecto")).toDF("value")

scala> df.show
+-----------------+
|            value|
+-----------------+
|1009|45|Diamond F|
|1010|46|DBX Vecto|
+-----------------+
val splitedViewsDF = df.withColumn("product_id", split($"value", "\\|").getItem(0)).withColumn("product_cat_id", split($"value", "\\|").getItem(1)).withColumn("product_name", split($"value", "\\|").getItem(2)).drop($"value")

scala> splitedViewsDF.show
+----------+--------------+------------+
|product_id|product_cat_id|product_name|
+----------+--------------+------------+
|      1009|            45|   Diamond F|
|      1010|            46|   DBX Vecto|
+----------+--------------+------------+
```

here you can get data by using getItem. Happy Hadoop

Comment: Thanks, Mahesh ...it indeed is better especially drop part.

Comment: Welcome I hope it helps you